# The connection Between slope of two connected lines.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, physics

So I was working on a very basic physics problem that had something to do with finding the height of a triangle(the velocity vs time graph)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHuKG.png)

A body starts from rest with an acceleration of 2m/s^2 till it attains the maximum velocity ,the decelerates to rest with 3m/s^2, If the total time taken was 10 secs, What was the maximum velocity?
I was able to solve it pretty fast and deduce that the height is 12.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPogi.png)

Then I had another idea , What If  Without changing the height and area/the total displacement I could make the triangle symmetrical? and divide t into two equal parts?

Then I could multiply the slope with the "run" and get the rise aka Vmax.
The mistake I made was thinking the average of the slope after the transformation would still be the same constant. From (2,-3) to (2.5 and -2.5).And I had good reason to assume that, because one inch taken from one line gets added to the other and the same goes for the area. Why not the slope?

Just imagine a 45/45/90 triangle. The first (upward) leg has a slope of 1, while the other leg has a slope of -1.

Shift the vertex to the left so the upward leg has a slope of 2. But the downward leg certainly doesn't have a slope of 0.

But we can certainly see that as the absolute value of one slope gets bigger the other one gets smaller.
Is there a way to know at what rate one slope changes in relation to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three points of interest in your diagram: $(0,0), (t_2,0), (t_1,v_{\text{max}})$. The area $A$ of the triangle is given by $A = \frac{t_2 v_{\text{max}}}{2}$.

Let's rewrite $A$ in terms of the two slopes you describe. This will give the desired relation for constant $A$. The first slope is $a_1 = \frac{v_{\text{max}}}{t_1}$. The second slope is $a_2 = \frac{v_{\text{max}}}{t_1 - t_2}$.

Thinking geometrically,
\begin{align}
A &= \frac{t_1 v_{\text{max}}}{2} + \frac{(t_2 - t_1)v_{\text{max}}}{2}
\\&= \frac{v_{\text{max}}^2}{2a_1} - \frac{v_{\text{max}}^2}{2a_2}
\\&= \frac{v_{\text{max}}^2}{2}\left( \frac{1}{a_1} - \frac{1}{a_2} \right)
\end{align}
Thus, the desired relation is
$$
A = \frac{v_{\text{max}}^2}{2}\left( \frac{1}{a_1} - \frac{1}{a_2} \right)
$$
Note that the height of the triangle is $v_{\text{max}}$ and the displacement is given by the area $A$.

Why is always a slippery question, but the flaw in your reasoning is essentially that area varies directly with time whereas acceleration varies inversely with it (in this problem). This is why the relation above assumes the form it does, with displacement depending on the harmonic mean of the accelerations, not their average or something like that.

### A Little More

I notice you make specific mention of a relationship between the rates at which $a_1$ and $a_2$ change. You can, of course, pass a derivative to figure that out. Holding $A$ and $v_\text{max}$ constant and differentiating implicitly, we find:
$$
0 = \frac{v_\text{max}^2}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{a_1^2} + \frac{1}{a_2^2} \frac{da_2}{da_1} \right)
$$
which yields the (perhaps satisfying) relationship:
$$
\frac{da_2}{da_1} = \left(\frac{a_2}{a_1}\right)^2
$$
Note that $A$ and $v_\text{max}$ drop out of this expression. We could have anticipated this since $\frac{1}{a_1} - \frac{1}{a_2}$ is a constant under the variations of the problem we are considering and does not depend on $A$ or $v_\text{max}$.

Comment: I was actually able to find out the relation you gave me. But I don't care about that problem in particular. We can graphically see that if I change the slope of 1 line the slope of the other line changes, It definitely is not the average when the triangle becomes an isosceles triangle. If it isn't the average then what is it? Is it even possible to find the relation? or is it just a stupid question?

Comment: See my edit, but note that the expression you obtained answers your question. If $v_\text{max}$ and displacement are held constant, then the harmonic mean of the accelerations is constant.

Comment: oh god, thank you. This is what i was looking for. so instead of 2.5 what should have been the the value of the slope? just dont answer this if your busy , I can figure this out.

Comment: Simply solve the equation $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{-3} = \frac{1}{a'} - \frac{1}{-a'}$. The $a'$ will be your "symmetrized acceleration." This is, by the way, precisely the harmonic mean of the absolute value of the accelerations. This is why identifying constants is so useful in physics. We can drop all the unnecessary parameters from our calculation and just equate two expressions for the same constant. Same trick as when you solve an energy conservation problem.

Comment: Here's a fun challenge problem to consider: What's the most "efficient" acceleration pattern? In other words, what $a_1$ and $a_2$ get you to $v_\text{max}$ and back to $0$ in the lest time $t_2$? Can you explain why without using calculus? (I'm not sure I can)

Comment: a 90 degree triangle? where a2 lim goes to -infinity? Could you explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: My problem is not well-posed as stated. You should assume $v_{\text{max}}$ is fixed but $A$ can vary.